# ASP.NET MVC3 Chart Control Performance/Best Practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I am currently using the Chart Control from `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` to dynamically creating 10 chart images from data that comes from a MySQL database with the help of the Entity Framework. The type of chart in question is fastline and they are created within a controller to be serve to a view as well as to be saved to disk.

Can the serve and save functionality of the chart images become a bottleneck with multiple users accessing the site? Also, are there any best practices when it comes to serving and saving the charts?

Thank you for any help or comment on this subject.

***Edit: this is for an intranet site.**

Comment: Before someone asks, I can't post any code because there are intellectual property rights involved... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only use the [Chart Control](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c) from MS if it's an **intranet app**, if it's an Online application I always go with [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

it's way more simple as it's only a `<img>` tag and you can have as much as you want, Google will handle the bandwidth.

When using MSCC, I tend to choose memory if there are only 100 users, if more, I have to go with saving to a physical place.

```
<add key="ChartImagehandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=20" />
```

on one of my last online projects (ASP.NET MVC) I used Google charts to display 26 charts on that page (each client had diff stats):

[image]